# Tracking for Booster Badge appears to be broken

Tags: support, bug

I've made two recent promotions that generated a lot of activity. An *Announcer* badge was awarded promptly. However, the *Booster* badge and *Publicist* badge were not forthcoming.

The Twitter tracking shows 1,139 link clicks:

[image]

And Stack Overflow question tracking showed matching results with 1,702 views.

[image]

This isn't the first time with this problem in the past two weeks. I also have two promotional tweets for [Filter a Set for Matching String Permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857962/filter-a-set-for-matching-string-permutations/44858212#44858212) which shows 1,376 views on Stack Overflow, and the tweet link tracking shows 596 clicks for https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/881060243475771393 and 339 links clicks for https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/883428369114685440.

My question is whether something is broken in the tracking? Given the data, the only other hypothesis that most of the Twitter link clicks were from a handful of non-unique IP addresses and that substantially all of the traffic shown on the Stack Overflow tracking counts were organic from Stack Overflow and not due to the tweeted links. This hypothesis seems unlikely given the high numbers of unique "likes" on the tweets and the relatively low traffic visiting the questions until I posted the promotional tweets.

Apologies in advance if this question reflects a deep understanding of what those badges mean and how they are tracked. Right now, it just doesn't make sense to me how successful promotions are only triggering the *Announcer* badge within a few minutes of the tweet but that the *Booster* and *Publicist* badges don't appear the totals accumulate to much large values.

Comment: Twitter link tracking and SO views can easily count things differently; it could be *the same user* clicking the link more than once is only counted once towards the badge. Not that I'm party to the exact rules.

Comment: I have noticed recently a huge raise in my announcer badge (AB) attributions. In the sole month of June 2017, I received nearly the same amount of AB in year 2016. Either my links get popular or something is broken. Unfortunately I don't know who click/visit my links (mostly link to SO answers or questions).